# Android app builds debug successfully but cannot find R.id of menu items when doing a release build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The debug build  works perfectly, but whenever I try to generate a signed APK from AndroidStudio it cannot find the R.id of my menu items.

Here is my menu.xml file

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/actionsearch"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/actionlogin"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
    android:title="Login"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/actionadddeal"
    android:title="Add Deal"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/actioneditvenue"
    android:title="Edit Venue"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

And here is the output from gradle when doing a release build for one sample file:

```
path\to\VenueDetailPagerActivity.java
Error:(109, 53) error: cannot find symbol variable actionlogin
Error:(109, 84) error: cannot find symbol variable actioneditvenue
Error:(109, 106) error: cannot find symbol variable actionadddeal
Error:(109, 167) error: cannot find symbol variable actionlogin
Error:(263, 22) error: cannot find symbol variable actioneditvenue
Error:(272, 22) error: cannot find symbol variable actionadddeal
```

The strange thing is, all other resource IDs have no issues. It's **only** the IDs from my menu.xml and **only** when generating a signed APK. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: post the java part too.

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by me forgetting to add this line to the top of the .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

But now follow up question is, why does this not cause problems for a local debug build but causes issues when generating a signed APK?